# Looping the cells and getting the count of a string value in all the sheets and printing the count sequence in another column in respective sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I stuck with a problem in excel, also new to VBA macro.
I have 4 sheets (sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3, Sheet 4) in a excel file which consists of same two columns in all the Sheets. Columns namely "Person name" and "Sequence Count"
My sheets looks like this:

```
Sheet 1
Person name | Sequence Number
John            
John
John
Mathew
Prince
Raj
Raj
Whale
```

```
Sheet 2
Person name | Sequence Number
John            
John
Mathew
Mathew
Prince
Prince
Raj
Raj
Raj
Whale
Whale
```

```
Sheet 3
Person name | Sequence Number
John            
John
John
John
Mathew
Prince
Sandy
Raj
Raj
Raj
Whale
```

Now after running the desired Macro, I need the output in this format

```
Sheet 1
Person name | Sequence Number
John            1
John            2
John            3
Mathew          1
Prince          1
Raj             1
Raj             2
Whale           1
```

```
Sheet 2
Person name | Sequence Number
John            4
John            5
Mathew          2
Mathew          3
Prince          2
Prince          3
Raj             3
Raj             4  
Raj             5
Whale           2
Whale           3
```

```
Sheet 3
Person name | Sequence Number
John            6
John            7
John            8
John            9
Mathew          4
Prince          4
Sandy           1
Raj             6
Raj             7
Raj             8
Whale           4
```

I mean to say, In the sheet 1, Value named "John" has 4 counts so it is printed in sequence number 1,2,3,4 and in sheet 2, the same Value "John" has again appeared 2 times, so in the sequence number column the count has continued from sheet 1 (5,6). As the value changes to "Mathew" in the sequence number column it has allotted the count (1) Sheet 1, In sheet 2 for the Particular value "Mathew" the count is incremented from sheet 1 and it is printed, as of same in the sheet 3. Now, this should apply for all the values.

Please help me regarding this, as the data is huge it is impossible to manipulate manually.
Please show me the way in macros. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem (and it should, I tested it) please mark it as such. If you are having a problem, let me know. Thx

Comment: @JulienMarrec Julien Thanks a lot It works fine... But i need to edit the code for large data. that I will try to take care of. But whenever I run the code a error is popping up. "Run time error:'9'" "Subscript out of range" and in editor it is pointing to `Set wS = Sheets(Shts(i))` Can u help me out in this, please... Also i have added the Reference when you have mentioned...

Comment: @JulienMarrec While adding the reference, Do I need to add any code in respect to that?

Comment: No, the reference is added and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code and add a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"  (Tools > Reference) so you can use a dictionary structure

```
Sub CountOccurence()
' Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oDict = New Dictionary
Dim Shts() As Variant
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim r As Integer, rLast As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Shts = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

For i = 0 To 3 Step 1

    Set wS = Sheets(Shts(i))

    rLast = wS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For r = 2 To rLast Step 1

        If Not (oDict.Exists(wS.Cells(r, 1).Value)) Then

            oDict.Add wS.Cells(r, 1).Value, 1

        Else

            oDict.Item(wS.Cells(r, 1).Value) = oDict.Item(wS.Cells(r, 1).Value) + 1

        End If

        wS.Cells(r, 2).Value = oDict.Item(wS.Cells(r, 1).Value)

    Next r

Next i

Set oDict = Nothing


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It works fine... But i need to edit the code for large data. that I will try to take care of. But whenever I run the code a error is popping up. "Run time error:'9'" "Subscript out of range" and in editor it is pointing to Set wS = Sheets(Shts(i)) Can u help me out in this, please... Also i have added the Reference when you have mentioned...

Comment: Does it crash as is (works fine on my computer)? Or is it when you modify it? Are your sheets exactly named "Sheet1" "Sheet2" etc?

Comment: It prints the values perfectly, later the error is displayed!! Before modifying it pop ups the error!!! And the sheets are named as in the code.

Comment: Can you tell me on which line it does crash exactly?

Comment: Its done Julien. I made some minor modifications, such as in array declaration. It is working fine. Thanks a lot.